# How to save a .net XML Document to a path with an & in it

Tags: .net, encoding, string

I am saving an XMLDocument object to disk [using the Save (string) function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw229a22.aspx).  When I do this I get a "Could not find a par of the path" error.

I have tried passing the characters as "&", "&", "%26", "\26", and "\38".  What am I missing?  Note that I am not talking about the *content* of the file -- but the filename.

```
Dim todocument As New Xml.XmlDocument
todocument.LoadXml(fromXml.OuterXml)
todocument.Save(toPath)
```

Comment: Could you show the relevant code?

Comment: Not much to see but I did add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

& (ampersands) are perfectly legal to put in a filename/path.  2 things to check.

1. make sure the destination folder is there
2. try saving it to a filestream object instead.

Comment: Going to give you credit here for the 'destination folder' being missing... really my \'s were encoded when they weren't supposed to be throwing my whole path off.

Answer (score 0):

My particular problem was not that the &'s weren't encoded -- my '\'s in the path were encoded and they weren't supposed to be.